# I want to know the error in my code. This is to print sum of all even numbers till 1 to N

Tags: c++, loops, visual-c++, error-handling, sum

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i = 1;
    int sum;
    int N;
    cout << "Enter a number N: ";
    cin >> N;
    while(i<=N)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
        else
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

This is to print the sum of all even numbers till 1 to  N.

As I try to run the code, I am being asked the value of N but nothing is being printed ahead.

Comment: As soon as you encounter the first even `i`, you no longer increment `i` and just loop forever.

Comment: Can you please point your finger at the exact line which increments `i`, inside the loop, when the `if()` condition evaluates to `true`? P.S. The whole approach is wrong anyway. This is a simple mathematical formula. No loop, to manually add up anything, is necessary. This must be a puzzle from one of countless of web sites that have lists of random coding puzzles, that depend on mathematical tricks. If you don't know what the trick is, the resulting program fails because it takes too long, or fails to handle some edge case.

Comment: In any case, you don't even need a loop for this problem. You are computing a sum of an arithmetic progression; there's a closed-form formula for that.

Comment: Use some maths. The sum 1 + 2 + ... + N is N*(N+1)/2. The sum of the even numbers  2*1 + 2*2 + ... + 2*(N/2)  is 2 * (1 + 2 + ... + N/2).

Comment: If you really want to use a loop, generate the even numbers instead of looking for them: `for (int i = 2; i < n; i += 2) sum += i;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the variable `sum` is not initialized.

Secondly you need to increase the variable `i` also when it is an even number. So the loop should look at least like

```
while(i<=N)
{
    if(i%2 == 0)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
```

In general it is always better to declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.

So instead of the while loop it is better to use a for loop as for example

```
for ( int i = 1; i++ < N; ++i )
{
    if ( i % 2 == 0 ) sum += i;
}
```

Comment: And better than a `for` loop is `n*(n+2)/4`

Comment: @justANewbie I think that the purpose of the assignment is investigating loops.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
while(i<=N)
{
    if(i%2 == 0)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    else
    {
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Let's step through this. Imagine we're on the loop where `i = 2` and you've entered `N = 5`. In that case...

```
while(i <= N)
```

2 <= 5 is true, so we loop

```
if(i%2 == 0)
```

2 % 2 == 0 is true, so we enter this branch

```
sum = sum + i;
```

Update sum, then head back to the top of the loop

```
while(i <= N)
```

Neither `i` nor `N` have changed, so 2 <= 5 is still true. We still loop

```
if(i%2 == 0)
```

2 % 2 == 0 is still true, so we enter this branch again...

---

Do you see what's happening here? Since neither `i` nor `N` are updated, you'll continue entering the same branch and looping indefinitely. Can you think of a way to prevent this? What would need to change?

Also note that `int sum;` means that `sum` will have a garbage value (it's uninitialized). If you want it to start at 0, you'll need to change that to

```
int sum = 0;
```

Comment: Worth noting that `sum` is uninitialized.

Comment: @justANewbie Good catch. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

No loops are necessary and sum can be evaluated at compile time if needed too

```
// use unsigned, the whole excercise is pointless for negative numbers
// use const parameter, is not intended to be changed
// constexpr is not needed, but allows for compile time evaluation (constexpr all the things)
// return type can be automatically deduced
constexpr auto sum_of_even_numbers_smaller_then(const unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int m = (n / 2);
    return m * (m + 1);
}

int main()
{
    // compile time checking of the function
    static_assert(sum_of_even_numbers_smaller_then(0) == 0);
    static_assert(sum_of_even_numbers_smaller_then(1) == 0);
    static_assert(sum_of_even_numbers_smaller_then(2) == 2);
    static_assert(sum_of_even_numbers_smaller_then(3) == 2);
    static_assert(sum_of_even_numbers_smaller_then(7) == 12);
    static_assert(sum_of_even_numbers_smaller_then(8) == 20);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping infinitly when i is even because you don't increase it.
Better option would be this if you want to use that while loop :

```
while(i<=N)
    {
       if(i%2 == 0)
            sum = sum + i;
       
       i=i+1;
    }
    cout << sum;
```

If you don't need to do anything when the condition is false, just don't use an else.

Answer (score 0):

int main(){

```
int input;                  //stores the user entered number
int sum=0;                  //stroes the sum of all even numbers
repeat:
cout<<"Please enter any integer bigger than one: ";
cin>>input;
if(input<1)                 //this check the number to be bigger than one means must be positive integer.
    goto repeat;            // if the user enter the number less than one it is repeating the entry.
for(int i=input; i>0; i--){ // find all even number from your number till one and than totals it.
    if(i%2==0){
        sum=sum+i;
        int j=0;
        j=j+1;
        cout<<"Number is: "<<i<<endl;
    }
}
cout<<endl<<"The sum of all even numbers is: "<<sum<<endl;}
```

Copy this C++ code and run it, it will solve your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are **2 problems** with your program.

##### Mistake 1

The variable `sum` has not been **initialized**. This means that it has(holds) an **indeterminate value**. And using this uninitialized variable like you did when you wrote `sum = sum + i;` is **undefined behavior**.

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely** on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

This is why it is advised that:

> always initialize built in types in local/block scope.

##### Mistake 2

The second problem is that you're **not updating** the value of variable `i`.

##### Solution

You can solve these problems as shown below:

```
int main(){
    int i = 1;
    int sum = 0; //INITIALIZE variable sum to 0
    int N;
    cout << "Enter a number N: ";
    cin >> N;
    while(i<=N)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
        
        i = i + 1; //update(increase i)
       
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For more reading(technical definition of) on undefined behavior you can refer to [undefined behavior's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which mentions that: *there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program.*</sup>